# How do I get the Debug Bar back to code mode in XCode after opening a GPU Trace?

Tags: xcode, metal

I'm in the middle of debugging some C++ in XCode (13.1).

Separately I run an external executable and generate a metal gputrace. I open the gpu trace by double clicking on the file. This creates a new tab in XCode (wish it made its own window). At that point I can replay the GPU trace.

The moment I do the Debug Bar changes from

[image]

To this

[image]

Or this

[image]

I want to go back to debugging the code but I can't find any way to switch the toolbar back.

The Debug Navigator shows both a call stack for the C++ and a GPU trace. Clicking on an entry in the call stack moves the editor window to that function but the Debug Bar does not change.

How can I get the Debug Bar back to code mode from metal mode?